# Uncaught TypeError: messages[0] is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I'm trying to add a timestamp to every message in a chat app. There is a component called MessageHistory where I'm trying to do that.

```
function MessageHistory({ messages }) {
  const activeUser = useSelector((state) => state.activeUser)
  const date = new Date(messages[0].createdAt)
  const hour = date.getHours();
  const minute = date.getMinutes();
  const timestamp = `${hour.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${minute.toString().padStart(2,'0')}`;
  ....
  <Box mr={2}><span>{timestamp}</span></Box>
  ....
```

messages is the array containing all the messages of a chat. This piece of code throws a type error in the ui.

Comment: So what if there are no messages? When `messages` is an empty array, what would `messages[0]` be then?...... Exactly. So there's your problem.

Comment: Yeah that's a problem but even when `messages` is not empty, I still get this error.

Comment: That's not possible though (unless you stuff `undefined`s into your array). Please use a debugger and verify your assumptions. What is `messages` at that point exactly? (In reality, not in your expectations.)

Comment: I checked the contents of `messages` in the console. It's basically an array containing the id, timestamp, sender details etc. Initially while loading the page, the array appears to be empty and then it loads with the content a few seconds later.

Comment: Alright so the error happens while it's empty then. Otherwise `messages[0]` wouldn't be undefined. Just handle the case of an empty array and you should be good...

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check that if `messages` is an array and if yes then only try to access its elements. This will fix the error and you can handle the case in else block when `messages` is empty in case of initially loading the page.

```
function MessageHistory({ messages }) {
  const activeUser = useSelector((state) => state.activeUser);
  let timestamp = '';
  
  if (Array.isArray(messages) && messages.length > 0) {
    const date = new Date(messages[0].createdAt);
    const hour = date.getHours();
    const minute = date.getMinutes();
    timestamp = `${hour.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${minute.toString().padStart(2,'0')}`;
  } else {
    console.log("Messages array is either null, undefined, or empty");
  }

  // Use timestamp variable here or perform any other operations
}
```